# Letter-substitution cipher, monoalphabetic ciphers without the use of HashMap

Tags: java, regex, encryption

**First**, user gives the key for the substitution. 
**Second**, user gives the filename to encrypt according to the key given.

Substitution should be like this:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
becomes 
**kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe**

Capital letters stays capital, for example, if the character is 'A'->'K'
If it is not letter, then it stays the same (preserves white spaces of the filetext)

This what I came up with:

```
public static void encrypt(){
        //System.out.println(inText);
        for(int j=0;j<inText.length()-1; j++){
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
                if(letters[i]-inText.charAt(j) ==0){
                    outText = inText.replace(inText.charAt(j), userKey.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

only 'd'--->'r', not the rest of the text file. Need help with this!

sampleinput.txt:

> CS 3 Welcomes you!
>
> In this class, we will go through different materials.
>
> Each material is very important for the next material to understand.

Key:

> qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm

Comment: Please provide a sample encryption key and a input string to test on. You haven't mentioned what `sampleinput.txt` contains.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your `encode()` method is, that `outText` is always overriden by the next substitution.

```
outText = inText.replace(inText.charAt(j), userKey.charAt(i));
```

As `d` is the last character in your input text the last subsitution is stored in `outText`. Which is the substitution of `d` by `r`.

```
// plain   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
// userKey qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm
//            *
outText = inText.replace('d', 'r');
```

Maybe one addtional comment here.

```
if(ls.charAt(i)==inText.charAt(j)){
    outText = inText.replace(inText.charAt(j), userKey.charAt(i));
```

Explained for the last character in the input text "... understan**d**."

- with the `if` statement you check if the character at index `j` in the input text (which is `d`) is equal to a character at index `i` (at index 3) in the plain alphabet
- if this matches you take the character at index `i`  from the user key (which is `r`) to substitute
- then you replace `d` by `r` in the input text `inText`, which doesn't contain any of the previous substitutions

**edit** The problem is that you don't keep previous substitutions.

The first lowercase character is `e`

> CS 3 W**e**lcomes you!
>   In this class, we will go through different materials.
>   Each material is very important for the next material to understand.

which should be substituted by character `t`

> CS 3 W**t**lcom**t**s you!
>   In this class, w**t** will go through diff**t**r**t**nt mat**t**rials.
>   Each mat**t**rial is v**t**ry important for th**t** n**t**xt mat**t**rial to und**t**rstand.

As basis for this substitution you use `inText` (which is the plain text) and the result is stored in `outText`.

The next lowercase character is `l`

> CS 3 We**l**comes you!
>   In this class, we will go through different materials.
>   Each material is very important for the next material to understand.

which should be substituted by character `k`. As you again use as basis for the substitution `inText` the previous substitution `e -> t` is lost. And the result in `outText` is

> CS 3 We**k**comes you!
>   In this c**k**ass, we wi**kk** go through different materia**k**s.
>   Each materia**k** is very important for the next materia**k** to understand.

and so on.

A naive idea to solve this could be to assign the text after each subsitution to `inText`.

```
outText = inText.replace(inText.charAt(j), userKey.charAt(i));
inText = outText;
```

But then you would also subsitute characters which has been already subsituted and the result would be

> CS 3 Wckcccca ccc!
>   Ic ccca ckaaa, cc cckk cc ccacccc accccaccc caccacaka.
>   Eacc caccacak ca ccac ccccacacc cca ccc cccc caccacak cc ccacaacaca.

Your initial idea was already in the right direction. To avoid the multiple substitions following would be more robust.

- take a character from the plain text one after each other
- if this character has a subsitution character
  -> add the substitution character to the output text
  else
  -> add the character from the plain text to the output text

Take this snippet as example

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String userKey = "qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm";
String plainText = "CS 3 Welcomes you!\n"
        + "In this class, we will go through different materials.\n"
        + "Each material is very important for the next material to understand.";
StringBuilder substitutedText = new StringBuilder(plainText.length());
for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
    char plainCharacter = plainText.charAt(i);
    int indexAlphabet = alphabet.indexOf(plainCharacter);
    if (indexAlphabet >= 0) {
        char substitutedCharacter = userKey.charAt(indexAlphabet);
        substitutedText.append(substitutedCharacter);
    } else {
        substitutedText.append(plainCharacter);
    }
}
System.out.println(substitutedText.toString());
```

**output**

> CS 3 Wtkegjta ngx!
>   Ih zioa ekqaa, vt vokk ug zisgxui royytsthz jqztsoqka.
>   Eqei jqztsoqk oa ctsn ojfgszqhz ygs zit htbz jqztsoqk zg xhrtsazqhr.

Comment: So the looping is the problem here?? If so, what do you suggest that I should do in this case?